# How to create a web debugging proxy like Charles on Mac

Tags: macos, cocoa, proxy

I would like to experiment with creating a web debugging proxy for Mac. While I’m experienced in Mac development, I’m not sure how to start approaching it. How does Charles work exactly?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop an application like Charles, you have to know framework [NetworkExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension).